# Gradle 'publishToMavenLocal' task not found. Please add the 'maven-publish' or 'maven' plugin

Tags: android, maven, gradle, jcenter, jitpack

I got an error when I deployed my library on jitpack  eoor are below. and I have use
Project full error is here --->

Build starting...
Start: Fri May 27 13:31:41 UTC 2022 67cf7f81daef
Git:
edb3881
commit edb38816aca77f5b11d1a2be6fbe604d3e1e088c
Author: Laxmi kant
Date:   Fri May 27 19:00:52 2022 +0530

this is my commit:-->   added all

```
    Init SDKMan
    Found Android manifest
    Android SDK version: . Build tools: 
    Found gradle
    Gradle build script
    Found gradle version: 7.0.2.
    Using gradle wrapper
    Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
    Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
   .10%.20%.30%.40%.50%.60%.70%.80%.90%.100%

   ------------------------------------------------------------
   Gradle 7.0.2
    ------------------------------------------------------------

   Build time:   2021-05-14 12:02:31 UTC
   Revision:     1ef1b260d39daacbf9357f9d8594a8a743e2152e

   Kotlin:       1.4.31
   Groovy:       3.0.7
   Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
    JVM:          1.8.0_292 (Private Build 25.292-b10)
   OS:           Linux 4.14.63-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 amd64

   0m3.269s
   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
   openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~16.04.1-b10)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
   Getting tasks: ./gradlew tasks --all
   WARNING:  > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
   Please specify Java version in jitpack.yml
   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
   JVM:          11.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.2+9)
   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
   Tasks: 

  ⚠️   WARNING:
   Gradle 'publishToMavenLocal' task not found. Please add the 'maven-publish' or 'maven' plugin.
   See the documentation and examples: https://docs.jitpack.io

   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
   Running: ./gradlew clean -Pgroup=com.github.codewith-fun -Pversion=edb38816ac -xtest -xlint 
   publishToMavenLocal

   Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
   Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
   See 
   https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * Where:
   Build file '/home/jitpack/build/app/build.gradle' line: 2

   * What went wrong:
   An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
   > Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Your project contains 2 or more modules with the same identification com.github.codewith- 
  fun:investwell
     at ":" and ":investwell".
     You must use different identification (either name or group) for each modules.

  * Try:
   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get 
   more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

   BUILD FAILED in 1s
   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
   Build tool exit code: 0
   Looking for artifacts...
   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
   Looking for pom.xml in build directory and ~/.m2
   2022-05-27T13:32:53.067115286Z
   Exit code: 0

   ⚠️ ERROR: No build artifacts found
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Open the project's build.gradle file.
2. Add the reference to the Maven plugin:
   `apply plugin: 'maven-publish'`
3. In the publishing section, specify the package properties (the generated package name will be groupId:artifactId). For example, we want to publish a .jar file (for the sake of length, the section content is reduced):

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId = 'com.github.mint'
                artifactId = 'mint-android-app'
                version = '0.0.4'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its Kotlin syntax would be:

```
    afterEvaluate {
        publishing {
            publications {
                create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
                    from (components["release"])
                    groupId = "com.github.mint"
                    artifactId = "mint-android-app"
                    version = "0.0.4"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How should this in gradle Kotlin syntax?

Comment: @LucasSousa ```plugins {
    `maven-publish`
}```